# PostgreSQL function dropped but is still available

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have only one schema in my database.
Inside that schema there is a function `sp_getData(varchar)`.

The problem i'm having is that if i drop the function, it is still available in the `pg_catalog` table and it can be used, although i dropped it.

I tried restarting the server to get rid of possible locks and it did not work. There is no duplicate of that function and it is not present in any other database or in the postgres schema on the server.

Do you know why this happens and how could i fix it?

Comment: Forgot to `commit`?

Comment: did not use `commit` on purpose. it used to work until today. now i'm thinking maybe somebody turned `autocommit off` for the entire server.

Comment: just checked the autocommit value and: `\echo :AUTOCOMMIT
on`